# Has Benezet's teaching experiment ever been reproduced?

Tags: primary-education, arithmetic-operations

In the 1930's, [Louis Bénézet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_P._B%C3%A9n%C3%A9zet), a superintendent of several schools in New Hampshire made the interesting experiment of teaching no formal arithmetic until grade 6:

> In the fall of 1929 I made up my mind to try the experiment of abandoning all formal instruction in arithmetic below the seventh grade and concentrating on teaching the children to read, to reason, and to recite - my new Three R's. And by reciting I did not mean giving back, verbatim, the words of the teacher or of the textbook. I meant speaking the English language. I picked out five rooms - three third grades, one combining the third and fourth grades, and one fifth grade.

He wrote about it in *[Teaching of Arithmetic I, II, III: The Story of an Experiment](http://www.inference.org.uk/sanjoy/benezet/)*, and the results seem very impressive. On the other hand, the findings are described in a style that seems more anecdotal than objective at times, and I would like to know more details.

1. Did Bénézet or someone else publish more details on the experiment (like the curriculum used, or how teachers were trained for it)? Did someone follow up on what happened with the children that were thought with this method?
2. Has the experiment been reproduced since then? Was further research done in this direction?

Comment: Great question. I tried to find out more (about 5 years ago) and had no luck.

It would be hard now to do it so large-scale, and to have the experimental and control groups so well-matched. Nowadays, anyone making a change this big would probably do lots of other parts of the schoolday differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find some further studies that *cited* the original writing on google scholar: [**link**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=11335995320848008936)

Mahajan ([**PDF**](https://people.rit.edu/svfsps/perc2001/Mahajan.pdf)) remarks that:

> Etta  Berman,
>   one  of  the  teachers  in  the  program,  studied
>   it  for  a  masters  degree  (1935);  she  gave  a
>   battery  of  quantitative  tests  to  106  control
>   and  82  experimental  students  in  the  sixth
>   grade. understatement:  ‘The  results  of  this  study
>   cast  doubt  upon  whether  we  are  justified  in
>   devoting five years to the drilling of formal
>   arithmetic’ (Berman 1935, p. 40).
>
> Despite  or  because  of  these  results,  in
>   1936  the  Manchester  school  board  ended
>   the experiment. Two years later Benezet was
>   forced out of his job, and today few know of
>   his  experiment.

The citation for this paper is given as:

> Berman, E. (1935). Result of deferring systematic teaching of arithmetic to grade six as disclosed by the deferred formal arithmetic plan at Manchester, New Hampshire (Doctoral dissertation, Boston University).

This is clearly incorrect, since it is *not* a doctoral dissertation: It is mentioned above as being for a "masters degree," and Boston University lists the thesis [**here**](https://open.bu.edu/handle/2144/20451) with the correct classification of Ed.M. (i.e., Master's in Education). The paper's 223 page PDF is available in full through archive: [**link**](https://archive.org/details/resultofdeferrin00berm)

An excerpt from p. 2:

[image]

Comment: Great findings!

Comment: @MichaelBächtold I hope you will update with what, if anything, you do using these leads!